# Incomplete string received from slot with PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyserial

I have an application which sends data over the serial port (using pyserial) to an external module which answers back upon reception.  I have a thread that monitors the incoming data and when there is, sends a signal through an emit function.  In the slot, I then analyze the packet received against a simplified hdlc protocol.  It's working fine but the only problem is that if the frame contains zeros (0x00) the string received by the slot is truncated.  So I'm assuming that the emit function passes the string up to a '0'.  Here is the code for the signal and for the slot.

```
def ComPortThread(self):
    """Thread that handles the incoming traffic. Does the basic input
       transformation (newlines) and generates an event"""
    while self.alive.isSet():               #loop while alive event is true
        text = self.serial.read(1)          #read one, with timeout
        if text:                            #check if not timeout
            n = self.serial.inWaiting()     #look if there is more to read
            if n:
                text = text + self.serial.read(n) #get it
            self.incomingData.event.emit(text)

@QtCore.Slot(str)
def processIncoming(self, dataIn):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    for byte in dataIn:
        self.hexData.append(int(binascii.hexlify(byte),16))
    ....
```

For example, if I print the content of the variable "text" in ComPortThread I could get:

> 7e000a0300030005

and if I do the same for "dataIn", I get:

> 7e

I've read that QByteArray would keep the '0' but I've not been successful in using it (although I'm not sure if I used it right).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm okay looking over the [QtSlot decorator](http://pythonxy.googlecode.com/hg-history/4ef4255f59b092a123a5788c821434d9fe94aee9/src/python/PyQt4/PLATLIB/PyQt4/doc/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) the form is:

```
PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSlot(types[, name][, result])
Decorate a Python method to create a Qt slot.

Parameters: 
types – the types that define the C++ signature of the slot. Each type may be a Python type object or a string that is the name of a C++ type.
name – the name of the slot that will be seen by C++. If omitted the name of the Python method being decorated will be used. This may only be given as a keyword argument.
result – the type of the result and may be a Python type object or a string that specifies a C++ type. This may only be given as a keyword argument.
```

Also it looks like since pyserial's read returns a [bytes python type](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read):

```
read(size=1)¶
Parameters: 
size – Number of bytes to read.
Returns:    
Bytes read from the port.
Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.

Changed in version 2.5: Returns an instance of bytes when available (Python 2.6 and newer) and str otherwise.
```

Though as noted with version 2.5 and python 2.6. With that in mind I'd look into making sure you're up to both versions mentioned and try:

```
@QtCore.Slot(bytes)
def processIncoming(self, dataIn):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    for byte in dataIn:
        self.hexData.append(int(binascii.hexlify(byte),16))
    ....
```

And see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I get the same result.  For now, I applied a big fat patch by using ".encode("hex")" before calling the emit() function.  I then decode within the slot.  That works out for me but it feels like using a hammer to insert a screw.

Comment: @jfmorin You're on 2.5 pyserial or greater with Python 2.6 or greater correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm on 2.6 for pyserial with Python 2.7.